# How to transform rename fields for different topics using SMT

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have multiple topics that needs to rename the fields in the schema status it shows `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table: topic2 is missing field ([SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRING}, name='stand_user', isPrimaryKey=false}]`

So my configuration is this

```
"topics":"topic1, topic2",
"transforms":"RenameField",
"transforms.RenameField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.RenameField.renames":"user:stand_user, user:session_user",
```

Where the stand_user is part of topic1 but session_user is part of topic2
Right now topic2 is erroring because it can't fine stand_user even though stand_user should only be in topic1. I tried to separate it as

```
"topics":"topic1, topic2",
"transforms":"RenameTopic1Field, RenameTopic2Field",
"transforms.RenameTopic1Field.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.RenameTopic1Field.renames":"user:stand_user",
"transforms.RenameTopic2Field.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.RenameTopic2Field.renames":"user:session_user",
```

But then the next field in the rename failed same error
Any suggestion to separate the topic rename

Answer (score 1):

Transforms apply to all topics in the config

If you can't apply a particular transform to a single topic consumed by that connector, it'll halt the connector from reading all other topics, so you must create a separate config to isolate the desired behavior

Comment: Does this mean I cannot separate the transform as RenameTopic1Field, RenameTopic2Field. I will always have to create another connector in order to satisfy the SMT? Wont that be a lot of connectors? It is because I am renaming only 1 field in the first topic, while i have another renaming field for the second topic. Cant I put both renaming fields into one config. Why did the connector said it is running and messages were able to consume then the connector stop after a day or so

Comment: As mentioned, Transforms apply to all topics. You cannot target individual fields within certain ones. More connectors will start more consumer threads, but it'll be more resilient to failure. Connectors don't restart themselves, so I'm not sure I understand the last question

Comment: isn't it better to troubleshoot if we have fewer connectors. It is because I am trying to put more topics into 1 connector while SMT to all the topics in the same connector since it is using the same db connection url. Also that way it can be distributed. I know that transforms apply to all topics but I am seeing that when I add a new topic i get like the original topic1 also gets affected. Topic 2 would then not have messages coming in or all topics in the same connector stops receiving messages Any idea

Comment: As answered, if the transform throws an exception for one topic (such as not being able to find a field), all topics in the same config stop being consumed. Therefore, separate configs with single topics make it easier to troubleshoot because only one topic on one connector /status endpoint would show as unhealthy